# OnetoOne unknown mappedBy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting a mappedBy unknown error between the relatioships of the following two entities.

It is a one to one relationship and the owner of the relationship should be the Story entity. I can't see my mistake in this code.

Both entities have getters and setters.

This is the first entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "story")
public class Story {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String link;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "story", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private DesignTechnique designTechnique;


    public Story(){

    }

    public Story(String name, String link){
        this.name = name;
        this.link= link;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link= link;
    }

    public DesignTechnique getDesignTechnique() {
        return designTechnique;
    }

    public void setDesignTechnique(DesignTechnique designTechnique) {
        this.designTechnique = designTechnique;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserStory{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", link='" + link+ '\'' +
                ", designTechnique='" + designTechnique + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the second entity:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "designTechnique")
public class DesignTechnique {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String technique;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "story_ID")
    private Story story;


    public DesignTechnique(){

    }

    public DesignTechnique(String technique){
        this.technique = technique;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTechnique() {
        return technique;
    }

    public void setTechnique(String technique) {
        this.technique = technique;
    }

    public Story getStory() {
        return story;
    }

    public void setStory(Story story) {
        this.story = story;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestdesignTechnique{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", technique='" + technique + '\'' +
                ", story='" + story+ '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.clusters.Model.Story.designTechnique, referenced property unknown: com.clusters.Model.DesignTechnique.story
```

### EDIT 2

I tried adding @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn instead of @JoinColumn in Design Entity, getting same error.

I have generated the getters and setters in both entities. So no typo's in these things.

Comment: can you post a full Stacktrace?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic Added the error

Comment: Try leaving away `mappedBy = "story",`, or better, read the javaDoc to  `mappedBy`

Comment: @HerrDerb If I understand it correctly mappedBy is needed to tell which one is the owner in a bidirectional relation

Comment: Alright, another try :) Within your `DesginTechnique` use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` instead of  `@JoinColumn(name ="story_ID")`
[hibernate-one-to-one-relationship](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: @Urban Do you have getters and setters for story in DesignTechnique? If yes are they maybe named differently than getStory and setStory?

Comment: @HerrDerb Tried it, same result

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I generated getters and setters

Comment: Can you show the full entities then? With getters and setters? The error you're getting is normally because you're referencing a wrong entity. Is the imported Story in DesignTechnique a different class? Do you have any other Class/Enum/etc with the same name?

Comment: @MárioFernandes added full entities

Comment: do you have a persistence.xml? Are both classes declared there?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hibernate bug !! see this :

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5695

Try to change the version of hibernate that you use.